# How to Send an Email to Myself When User Reports a Post

Tags: ios, swift, email

Im building a user created content app and I need to conform to the required guide lines. I am implementing a report feature in which I want an email sent to myself that sends the usersID, postID and post content for review. I am able to use the email composer to have the user send an email however, I dont want the user to need to send the email, I want it to automatically send when the button is pressed. Is there any way for me to implement this. This is what I have...

```
 func sendEmail() {
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["random@gmail.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("Inappropriate Content Report")

    if post.imageUrl != nil {
        let data: Data!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: post.imageUrl!)

        do {
            try data = Data(contentsOf: url)
            composeVC.setMessageBody("Reported Content: \n \n \(post.caption) \n \n Reported User: \(post.userID) \n \n PostID: \(post.postID)", isHTML: false)
            composeVC.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: post.imageUrl!)
        } catch let error {
            print("CHRIS THERE IS AN ERROR", error)
        }

    } else {
        composeVC.setMessageBody("Reported Content: \n \n  \(post.caption) \n \n Reported User: \(post.userID) \n \n PostID: \(post.postID)", isHTML: false)
    }
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Use a service like SendGrid or something similar.

Comment: For more similar questions with answers, search  for `[ios] send email without user interaction`  ...

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible using MFMailComposeViewController

Workaround for this is you have to create web service and pass data to it and your server can send mail. This is will result same as your requirement.